# A brief int counter

Tags: number-sequence, english

The following infinite sequence is used by those taking first steps in maths.

> 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ?

Find the next number.

Comment: +1 just for the title!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think the next number is

> $5$

The sequence is

> The number of *unique* letters in the English spelling of each of the cardinal numbers, e.g, $3 \rightarrow$ THREE which has $4$ unique letters: 'T','H','R' and 'E'. 
>  The next number, $15$, has $5$ unique letters in its spelling: 'F', 'I', 'T', 'E' and 'N', hence the answer is $5$.